# My program runs without code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xna

I'am having a very weird problem with my program after I have been working on my XNA game, I don't know where my program get it's code from, because when I out comment all my code in visual studio 2008 c#, nothing should work, but the game still starts normally, without having any problems. I don't know how I can solve this problem, and I hope that one of you guys know why my program still is running fine after I out commented all my code to check. If I remove all my code the program also still runs, I hope one of you guys can tell me where Visual Studio 2008 is getting it's code from, or a solution for this problem.

Please tell me when you are having trouble understanding my problem.

Comment: You are almost certainly not running the program you think you are running.

Comment: We can't see your solution... how would we know where the code is? Either you are running an old build, running something other than what you think you are, or you have code somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you've commented logic that's ultimately called from event handlers. Anyways, I'd say to comment the entry point if you really want it to stop working. I can't really know (nor anyone else) without actually seeing your code/solution.

Comment: Read up on clearing visual studio cache http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: But, when I open visual studio 2008, and choose the solution .sln file, and just comment out all code, it won't react, will this have to do because I also have vs 2010 and 2012 installed on my pc on windows 8?

Comment: My backup files map of visual studio 2008 is empty

Comment: What is wrong? It just doesn't work, I tried everything, but I just want to know which file my project is running to start up

Answer (score 5):

Odd's are that you have an error in your code and its not compiling. VS is probably running the last successful build of your program.

Comment: Is there a way to use the code I am editing now, it is about the standard classe called: Game 1

Comment: Check to see if there are errors in your code and fix them. Once you do that you should be able to compile and execute the program as you want to